# How can I fix this 'int android.content.SharedPreferences.getInt error?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am new to coding and I recently got an error that I can't find a way to fix it. I know what a NullPointerException is, but I don't see a solution to this. Is a code from GitHub (not all of it), so I don't know what's wrong. I tried to document myself. If there is someone who can help me I would appreciate it.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.content.SharedPreferences.getInt(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference


 public class RunningFragment extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener {

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

public RunningFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

//Activity Views
private TextView dayRecordText;
private TextView stepText;
private TextView timeText;
private TextView orientationText;
private TextView distanceText;
private TextView achievedText;
private TextView speedText;

//Preferences are used to remember the step record of the day
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private int dayStepRecord;


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);


        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        stepDetectorSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magnetometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

        if (stepDetectorSensor == null)
            showErrorDialog();

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_running, container, false);
    //Initialize views
    stepText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.stepText);
    timeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
    speedText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.speedText);
    distanceText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.distanceText);
    orientationText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.orientationText);
    achievedText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.achievedText);
    setViewDefaultValues();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    dayStepRecord = sharedPreferences.getInt(SettingsActivity.DAY_STEP_RECORD, 3) * 1000;
    dayRecordText.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.record), dayStepRecord));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just put

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
```

outside `if (getArguments() != null) {` statement (next line after closing `}` bracket) in `onCreate`

in fact arguments null-check should be applied only when you want to use these arguments (methods `getArguments().getString(...)`), sensors and shared preferences should be initiated anyway/always

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    } // new closing bracket in here

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        stepDetectorSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magnetometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

        if (stepDetectorSensor == null)
            showErrorDialog();

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    //} was here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did just as suggested, but nothing changed tho.

Comment: Actually, it fixed the error, but now I have a new one. I'll edit my question.

Comment: question are single-purpose, if you have new problem - post new question, this is already answered (but sadly not accepted...)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the int named SettingsActivity.DAY_STEP_RECORD from sharedPreferences. Make sure that sharedPreferences is defined and that SettingsActivity.DAY_STEP_RECORD exists within the sharedpreferences.